# How to get the partition results of machine learning in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I know that when I execute the LogisticRegression.fit(), this operation will split the data automatically in spark MLlib.

My first question :
For example: I want to split the data to 10 sets. Then, they are run a learning algorithm parallel. Then, I can get ten hypotheses, which can do the other algorithm to find a final better hypothesis.

The idea is that I split the data 10 sets randomly. Then I run LogisticRegression.fit() in each fold (for-loop?). Therefore, I can the each fold's results. However, I think it may not be a good way because of spending more time.

What is the better way when I want to get the each partition's results?

The other question is:
In LogisticRegressionModel class, can I say "the val weights is the hypothesis of the model." ?

Comment: Maybe what you want is a [CrossValidator](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator)

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto No, I design a new algorithm. I try to use the partition's results to find the best hypothesis iteratively (like bottom-up). However, I don't like how to find the partition's results in spark.